# Nested ifs to get values from different column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df, I want to fill values in a column, based on the condition applied to other column

Structure of DF, After ID there are some columns:

```
ID ......  col1  col2   col3   col4
1          A1     A1     A1     A1
2          G3            D5
3          R6             
4                 Q3
5          M5     N8
```

I want to create two new column called 'final_col' and 'status', where 'final_col' has value from col1 or col2 or col3 or col4 depending on which col had first non-blank (not null/NaN) value.

The column 'status' is just the name of the column

Expected Output:

```
ID ...... col1  col2   col3   col4    final_col     status
1         A1     A1     A1     A1     A1            col1
2                G3            D5     G3            col2
3         R6                   L4     R6            col1
4                                     Not_found     Not_found
5                M5     N8            M5            col2
```

I know how to do this in excel, with nested ifs as so, assuming ID is cell 'A1'

In the first row of 'final_col':

```
=IF(A2<>"",A2,IF(B2<>"",B2,IF(C2<>"",C2,IF(D2<>"",D2,"Not_found"))))
```

For column 'status'

```
=IF(A2<>"","col1",IF(B2<>"","col2",IF(C2<>"","col3",IF(D2<>"","col4","Not_found"))))
```

P.S: Please use column names in your solution, and not index because the structure of the data frame may vary (order of the columns).

Comment: Why are you expecting to get `Not found` for row 4? Should it be `Q3` from your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html). If you can all `NaN` values in some row in columns `col1` to `col4` use:

```
print df

   ID col1 col2 col3 col4
0   1   A1   A1   A1   A1
1   2  NaN   G3  NaN   D5
2   3   R6  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   5  NaN   M5   N8  NaN

def f1(x):
    if x.first_valid_index() is None:
        return 'Not_found'
    else:
        return str(x.first_valid_index())

def f2(x):
    if x.first_valid_index() is None:
        return 'Not_found'
    else:
        return x[x.first_valid_index()]


df['status'] = df.ix[:, df.columns.tolist().index("col1") :].apply(f1, axis=1)

df['final_col'] = df.ix[:, df.columns.tolist().index("col1") :].apply(f2, axis=1)

print df

   ID col1 col2 col3 col4     status  final_col
0   1   A1   A1   A1   A1       col1         A1
1   2  NaN   G3  NaN   D5       col2         G3
2   3   R6  NaN  NaN  NaN       col1         R6
3   4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  Not_found  Not_found
4   5  NaN   M5   N8  NaN       col2         M5
```

Comment: Could you modify your answer to work if the columns 'col1' appeared after say ten other columns, i.e first_valid_index would not point to col1

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html):

```
In [105]: df
Out[105]:
   ID col1 col2 col3 col4
0   1   A1   A1   A1   A1
1   2  NaN   G3  NaN   D5
2   3   R6  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   5  NaN   M5   N8  NaN

df['status'] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index(), axis=1)

df['final_col'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x[x['status']] if x['status'] != None else 'Not found', axis=1)

df['status'].fillna('Not found', inplace=True)

In [129]: df
Out[129]:
   ID col1 col2 col3 col4     status  final_col
0   1   A1   A1   A1   A1       col1         A1
1   2  NaN   G3  NaN   D5       col2         G3
2   3   R6  NaN  NaN  NaN       col1         R6
3   4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  Not found  Not found
4   5  NaN   M5   N8  NaN       col2         M5
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but will your solution work if column 'col1' appeared after say 10 other column?

Comment: @user3875610 do you have names like `col` + number? I mean could you sort your dataframe columns prior that operation?